# 404 Not Found; Apache Server can't load simple php file

Tags: php, apache

So I have been given a static site. It was built with php. Unfortunately I am not familiar with it. However, I thought that shouldn't be much of a concern as my goal is just trying to serve it locally so I can update it.

This is the directory where the site lives...

```
/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/
```

I configured Apache with the following. (I am on a macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.)

***private/etc/hosts***

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
#127.0.0.1         localhost

127.0.0.1         fragrances.christinaaguilera
127.0.0.1         www.fragrances.christinaaguilera

255.255.255.255   broadcasthost
::1               localhost
```

***/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf***

This is what I figured is the most important part to change... Am I wrong?

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/"
<Directory "/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

***/private/etc/apache2/users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz.conf***

```
  <Directory "Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

And finally the **config.php** file:

```
<?php

    // error_reporting(E_ALL);
    // ini_set("display_errors", 1);

    session_start();

    $validLanguages = array('EN'=>'en','DE'=>'de'/*,'RU'=>'ru','PT'=>'pt','HU'=>'hu','NL'=>'nl'*/);

    switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
    {


        case 'fragrances.christinaaguilera' || 'www.fragrances.christinaaguilera':
        {
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set("display_errors", 1);

            if(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,7)!='http://')
            {
                $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            }

            define('ROOT_PATH',  '/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/fragrances.christinaaguilera.dev');
            define('TEMPLATE_PATH', ROOT_PATH.'templates/');
            define('XML_PATH',    ROOT_PATH.'xml/');
            define('ROOT_URL',    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/');
            define('MEDIA_ROOT_URL','/');
            define('CSS_ROOT_URL',  MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'css/');
            define('JS_ROOT_URL',   MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'js/');
            define('IMG_ROOT_URL',  MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'images/');

            break;
        }
        // case'192.168.0.206':
        // {
        //  error_reporting(E_ALL);
        //  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
        //
        //  if(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,7)!='http://')
        //  {
        //      $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        //  }
        //
        //  define('ROOT_PATH',  '/media/sf_public_html/aguilera-microsite/branches/20141007_responsive/');
        //  define('TEMPLATE_PATH', ROOT_PATH.'templates/');
        //  define('XML_PATH',    ROOT_PATH.'xml/');
        //  define('ROOT_URL',    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/aguilera-microsite/branches/20141007_responsive/');
        //  define('MEDIA_ROOT_URL','http://192.168.0.206/aguilera-microsite/branches/20141007_responsive/');
        //  define('CSS_ROOT_URL',  ROOT_URL.'css/');
        //  define('JS_ROOT_URL',   ROOT_URL.'js/');
        //  define('IMG_ROOT_URL',  ROOT_URL.'images/');
        //
        //  break;
        // }

        // case'137.183.87.135':
        // {
        //  error_reporting(E_ALL);
        //  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
        //
        //  if(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,7)!='http://')
        //  {
        //      $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        //  }
        //
        //  define('ROOT_PATH',  '/content/aguilera/docs/responsive/');
        //  define('TEMPLATE_PATH', ROOT_PATH.'templates/');
        //  define('XML_PATH',    ROOT_PATH.'xml/');
        //  define('ROOT_URL',    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/responsive/');
        //  define('MEDIA_ROOT_URL','http://137.183.87.135:4064/content/aguilera/docs/responsive/');
        //  define('CSS_ROOT_URL',  ROOT_URL.'css/');
        //  define('JS_ROOT_URL',   ROOT_URL.'js/');
        //  define('IMG_ROOT_URL',  ROOT_URL.'images/');
        //
        //  break;
        // }

        //case'137.183.87.139':
        //{
        //  // error_reporting(E_ALL);
        //  // ini_set("display_errors", 1);
        //
        //  if(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,7)!='http://')
        //  {
        //      $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        //  }
        //
        //  define('ROOT_PATH',  '/content/aguilera/docs/restage/');
        //  define('TEMPLATE_PATH', ROOT_PATH.'templates/');
        //  define('XML_PATH',    ROOT_PATH.'xml/');
        //  define('ROOT_URL',    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/restage/');
        //  define('MEDIA_ROOT_URL','http://137.183.87.139:4064/restage/');
        //  define('CSS_ROOT_URL',  MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'css/');
        //  define('JS_ROOT_URL',   MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'js/');
        //  define('IMG_ROOT_URL',  MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'images/');
        //
        //  break;
        //}

        //case'137.183.87.140':
        //{
        //  // error_reporting(E_ALL);
        //  // ini_set("display_errors", 1);
        //
        //  if(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,7)!='http://')
        //  {
        //      $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        //  }
        //
        //  define('ROOT_PATH',  '/content/aguilera/docs/restage/');
        //  define('TEMPLATE_PATH', ROOT_PATH.'templates/');
        //  define('XML_PATH',    ROOT_PATH.'xml/');
        //  define('ROOT_URL',    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/restage/');
        //  define('MEDIA_ROOT_URL','http://137.183.87.140:4064/restage/');
        //  define('CSS_ROOT_URL',  MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'css/');
        //  define('JS_ROOT_URL',   MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'js/');
        //  define('IMG_ROOT_URL',  MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'images/');

        //  break;
        //}

        default:
        {
           // error_reporting(E_ALL);
           // ini_set("display_errors", 1);

            if(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,7)!='http://')
            {
                $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            }

            if(!preg_match('~elizabetharden~',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])){
                // PROD instance root path
                define('ROOT_PATH',  'D:/Sites/wwwroot/fragrances.christinaaguilera.com/content/aguilera/docs/restage/');
            } else {
                // DEV instance root path
                define('ROOT_PATH',  'D:/Sites/wwwroot/christinaaguilera.elizabetharden.net/content/aguilera/docs/restage/');
            }

            define('TEMPLATE_PATH', ROOT_PATH.'templates/');
            define('XML_PATH',    ROOT_PATH.'xml/');
            define('ROOT_URL',    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/');

            if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_SSL"])){
                // define('MEDIA_ROOT_URL','https://secure.footprint.net/perfumes-christinaaguilera-com/restage/v_23/');
            } else {
                // define('MEDIA_ROOT_URL','http://media.perfumes.christinaaguilera.com/restage/v_23/');
            }

            define('MEDIA_ROOT_URL','/');

            define('CSS_ROOT_URL',  MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'css/');
            define('JS_ROOT_URL',   MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'js/');
            define('IMG_ROOT_URL',  MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'images/');

             break;
        }

    }
```

**UPDATE October 2nd**

So I have the alias working now:

[image]

But as you can see it's pointing to that **index.html** file in the Sites folder.

[image]

And I updated the **/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf**

```
  <Directory "Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/">
    AddLanguage en .en
    AddHandler perl-script .pl
    PerlHandler ModPerl::Registry
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Require host localhost
  </Directory>
```

- Now I can run pearl scripts... :)

**UPDATE October 2nd** as per msg...

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/fragrances.christinaaguilera/
    <Directory  "/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/fragrances.christinaaguilera/"
    ServerName fragrances.christinaaguilera
    ServerAlias www.fragrances.christinaaguilera
    <Directory  "/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/fragrances.christinaaguilera/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My latest config.php

```
<?php

    // error_reporting(E_ALL);
    // ini_set("display_errors", 1);

    session_start();

    $validLanguages = array('EN'=>'en','DE'=>'de'/*,'RU'=>'ru','PT'=>'pt','HU'=>'hu','NL'=>'nl'*/);

    switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
    {


        case 'fragrances.christinaaguilera' || 'www.fragrances.christinaaguilera':
        {
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set("display_errors", 1);

            if(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,7)!='http://')
            {
                $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            }

            define('ROOT_PATH',  '/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/fragrances.christinaaguilera/');
            define('TEMPLATE_PATH', ROOT_PATH.'templates/');
            define('XML_PATH',    ROOT_PATH.'xml/');
            define('ROOT_URL',    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/');
            define('MEDIA_ROOT_URL','/');
            define('CSS_ROOT_URL',  MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'css/');
            define('JS_ROOT_URL',   MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'js/');
            define('IMG_ROOT_URL',  MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'images/');

            break;
        }
        // case'192.168.0.206':
        // {
        //  error_reporting(E_ALL);
        //  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
        //
        //  if(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,7)!='http://')
        //  {
        //      $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        //  }
        //
        //  define('ROOT_PATH',  '/media/sf_public_html/aguilera-microsite/branches/20141007_responsive/');
        //  define('TEMPLATE_PATH', ROOT_PATH.'templates/');
        //  define('XML_PATH',    ROOT_PATH.'xml/');
        //  define('ROOT_URL',    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/aguilera-microsite/branches/20141007_responsive/');
        //  define('MEDIA_ROOT_URL','http://192.168.0.206/aguilera-microsite/branches/20141007_responsive/');
        //  define('CSS_ROOT_URL',  ROOT_URL.'css/');
        //  define('JS_ROOT_URL',   ROOT_URL.'js/');
        //  define('IMG_ROOT_URL',  ROOT_URL.'images/');
        //
        //  break;
        // }

        // case'137.183.87.135':
        // {
        //  error_reporting(E_ALL);
        //  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
        //
        //  if(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,7)!='http://')
        //  {
        //      $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        //  }
        //
        //  define('ROOT_PATH',  '/content/aguilera/docs/responsive/');
        //  define('TEMPLATE_PATH', ROOT_PATH.'templates/');
        //  define('XML_PATH',    ROOT_PATH.'xml/');
        //  define('ROOT_URL',    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/responsive/');
        //  define('MEDIA_ROOT_URL','http://137.183.87.135:4064/content/aguilera/docs/responsive/');
        //  define('CSS_ROOT_URL',  ROOT_URL.'css/');
        //  define('JS_ROOT_URL',   ROOT_URL.'js/');
        //  define('IMG_ROOT_URL',  ROOT_URL.'images/');
        //
        //  break;
        // }

        //case'137.183.87.139':
        //{
        //  // error_reporting(E_ALL);
        //  // ini_set("display_errors", 1);
        //
        //  if(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,7)!='http://')
        //  {
        //      $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        //  }
        //
        //  define('ROOT_PATH',  '/content/aguilera/docs/restage/');
        //  define('TEMPLATE_PATH', ROOT_PATH.'templates/');
        //  define('XML_PATH',    ROOT_PATH.'xml/');
        //  define('ROOT_URL',    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/restage/');
        //  define('MEDIA_ROOT_URL','http://137.183.87.139:4064/restage/');
        //  define('CSS_ROOT_URL',  MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'css/');
        //  define('JS_ROOT_URL',   MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'js/');
        //  define('IMG_ROOT_URL',  MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'images/');
        //
        //  break;
        //}

        //case'137.183.87.140':
        //{
        //  // error_reporting(E_ALL);
        //  // ini_set("display_errors", 1);
        //
        //  if(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,7)!='http://')
        //  {
        //      $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        //  }
        //
        //  define('ROOT_PATH',  '/content/aguilera/docs/restage/');
        //  define('TEMPLATE_PATH', ROOT_PATH.'templates/');
        //  define('XML_PATH',    ROOT_PATH.'xml/');
        //  define('ROOT_URL',    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/restage/');
        //  define('MEDIA_ROOT_URL','http://137.183.87.140:4064/restage/');
        //  define('CSS_ROOT_URL',  MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'css/');
        //  define('JS_ROOT_URL',   MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'js/');
        //  define('IMG_ROOT_URL',  MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'images/');

        //  break;
        //}

        default:
        {
           // error_reporting(E_ALL);
           // ini_set("display_errors", 1);

            if(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,7)!='http://')
            {
                $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            }

            if(!preg_match('~elizabetharden~',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])){
                // PROD instance root path
                define('ROOT_PATH',  'D:/Sites/wwwroot/fragrances.christinaaguilera.com/content/aguilera/docs/restage/');
            } else {
                // DEV instance root path
                define('ROOT_PATH',  'D:/Sites/wwwroot/christinaaguilera.elizabetharden.net/content/aguilera/docs/restage/');
            }

            define('TEMPLATE_PATH', ROOT_PATH.'templates/');
            define('XML_PATH',    ROOT_PATH.'xml/');
            define('ROOT_URL',    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/');

            if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_SSL"])){
                // define('MEDIA_ROOT_URL','https://secure.footprint.net/perfumes-christinaaguilera-com/restage/v_23/');
            } else {
                // define('MEDIA_ROOT_URL','http://media.perfumes.christinaaguilera.com/restage/v_23/');
            }

            define('MEDIA_ROOT_URL','/');

            define('CSS_ROOT_URL',  MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'css/');
            define('JS_ROOT_URL',   MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'js/');
            define('IMG_ROOT_URL',  MEDIA_ROOT_URL.'images/');

             break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have a subfolder for the actual site, under `/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/` ? eg. `/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/fragrances.christinaaguilera`

Comment: @Cemal Thanks for your response! Yes I do.

Comment: can you try http:// **www** .fragrances.christinaaguilera/fragrances.christinaaguilera/rootfile.php

Comment: @Cemal That didn't work, but thanks!

Comment: Since You're overriding rules defined in configs You've to allow that feature. Try to change: `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

Comment: Set the `DocumentRoot` of your aliased virtualhost to the root of the project: `DocumentRoot /Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/fragrances.christinaaguilera` and adjust your `Directory` directives. Because `rootfile.php` is inside that directory, right ?

Comment: @msg I made an update above based on what you just said. And where would I update the the `Directory` directives?
And yes the rootfile.php is indeed in the `fragrances.christinaaguilera/`

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz Only the ones on that `VirtualHost` context. Not necessary for `localhost`. Same goes for `DocumentRoot`, both urls will take you to the same place otherwise.

Comment: @msg So is my update correct?

Comment: @msg That didn't work, but I'm not confident I translated what you said correctly. Think you can bring you suggestion to an answer, So I have a step by step guide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache will route a request to a `VirtualHost` that matches `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` first, or the one labeled `_default_` or the first `VirtualHost` defined if there isn't one. Based on that, serves whatever file was requested, from the `DocumentRoot` directory for that `VirtualHost` or the `DirectoryIndex` defined if there is no file.

So, up to this point, given your (known) directory structure, you need the following configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/
    <Directory  "/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/fragrances.christinaaguilera/"
    ServerName fragrances.christinaaguilera
    ServerAlias www.fragrances.christinaaguilera
    <Directory  "/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/fragrances.christinaaguilera/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        DirectoryIndex rootfile.php
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that I changed the `MultiViews`, `AllowOverride` and `DirectoryIndex` settings.

Now, when you access `http://fragrances.christinaaguilera` Apache would normally try to serve `index.html` or similar file, but with `DirectoryIndex` will serve that file instead. With `AllowOverride All`, it'll check for existence of `.htaccess` and apply the rules in there but I've disabled it for now. We'll take it one step at a time.

You can check if apache is picking up your configuration by executing `apachectl -D DUMP_VHOSTS`. It should show you the defined `VirtualHosts`. If there is none, make sure your virtual host config file is being included in your main `httpd.conf` server config by looking for `Include` directives like:

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/*.conf
```

Make sure the path match and restart the service.

Once we get the `VirtualHost` up and running it's time to get the `.htaccess`. For that, we need to change `AllowOverride` back and get rid of the `DirectoryIndex` directive, leaving the `Directory` for the `VirtualHost` like this:

```
<Directory  "/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/fragrances.christinaaguilera/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>
```

And now, we should see the same redirection behaviour when accessing the site. With a bit of luck, we'll see the site. If not, we'll begin by commenting out the line `RewriteBase /restage`.

Most of the file **should** not be necessary for our purposes. I **think** we can get by with this minimal version to start:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /rootfile.php/$1 [L]
```

That's a quite standard clean url router setup. It translates to "redirect any request that is not a physical file or directory on disk to rootfile.php/uri".

Now try to access `http://fragrances.christinaaguilera/en/`.

Here's a breakdown for the rest of the file:

- The `AddType` directives tell apache to send mime headers for those specific file extensions. You might not need them if running a modern version of apache, but just to be sure...
- The `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` lines and following `RewriteRule` redirect to a canonical url (the www. version). Doesn't make much sense in development, unless it's to make sure there are no extra redirections.
- All the `RewriteRule hu/$ /en/ [R=301,L]` you shouldn't ever need, as it's handled on the php side (`if(!in_array($language, $validLanguages))`). They redirect to the english version. Except for the `/de/` one, that's still in use. Also leave the `lang/home$` redirections in there, just to be safe.

Finally the three potentially problematic lines:

```
RewriteBase /restage/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !microsite
RewriteRule ^(.*)v_([0-9]*)/(.*)$ /restage/$3 [L]
```

Can't say for sure what they do without more info in the internal links, but here is what they translate to:

- `RewriteBase` basically says "for **any** rewriting that occurs, prepend `/restage/` to it". This is file wide, so it would affect the `rootfile.php` redirection too. So it *should* be a restage directory inside your project with (mostly) the same files for this rules to make sense.
- The following two rules translate to "any request that is **not** a microsite **and** contains the string "v_" followed by numbers and a slash and any string, redirect to /restage/restage/any_string". There are two `/restages` in the translation because of the `RewriteBase`. That behaviour is what worries me the most, but as I said, need more info on the project structure. Looks like someone was working on adding some features to a copy of the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the .htaccess functionality, you'll need mod_rewrite enabled on your Apache server. To check for this, run the following command:

```
sudo apache2ctl -M
```

If you see rewrite_module in the list, you are good to go. If not, just enable it with the following command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

And restart Apache for the changes to take effect:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Are you sure the command is `sudo a2enmod rewrite`? As I got back `sudo: a2enmod: command not found`

Comment: I actually went into `private/etc/apache2/http.conf` and commented out `LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so` and ran `sudo apachectl -M     ` which resulted in seeing `rewrite_module (shared)` however after restarting still got a `404 Not found`

Comment: @msg Could you explain what I have to rename?

Comment: @msg Thanks, I renamed the file with the command you suggested but upon restarting and going to the path `http://localhost/~antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/fragrances.christinaaguilera.dev/rootfile.php` still got a 404 error.

Comment: `sudo a2enmode rewrite` - man author uses MacOS, not Debian or it's forks. Find such text: `I am on a macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.`

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz please run following in terminal and add output to Your question: `ls -la /Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/`  I suspect that Your scripts is in nested folder and it should be declared using `VirtualHost` directives.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare virtual host where You define hostname and document root.

Add following to the end of httpd.conf and restart apache:

```
<Directory "/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/fragrances.christinaaguilera/"> 
  Options Indexes MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>

NameVirtualHost *:80 

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Sites/fragrances.christinaaguilera"
  ServerName fragrances.christinaaguilera
  ServerAlias www.fragrances.christinaaguilera
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for helping. So I went `/private/etc/apache2/extra/ httpd.conf` and edited the file, now what should I do?

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz restart the apache and open: http://fragrances.christinaaguilera in browser

Comment: I got back `Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.`

Comment: Cool, thank you very much for helping figure this bugger out! I am in EST so is tomorrow like after 9:00AM EST ok?

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz sure.